# What semantic notions underlie 'articles' with legal apprenticeship?

Tags: legal-terms

Source: [*A Brief Introduction to Law in Canada*](http://emond.ca/a-brief-introduction-to-law-in-canada.html) (Mar. 2017). p. 265 Middle.

> Historically, in Canada, there was debate over rival methods for teaching law. Some members 
>   of the legal community believed that traditional English vocational methods for training 
>   lawyers should be followed. These methods were based on an apprenticeship model where- 
>   by law students served "under **articles**," and obtained practical experience and direct 
>   knowledge of the law by working with and under the supervision of a practising lawyer. 
>   This training could also be supplemented with law society lectures. On the other side of the 
>   legal education debate were those who favoured the idea of formal university training at a 
>   recognized law school, where professors (rather than practising lawyers) taught the law. 
>   The debate was resolved in favour of the current model, which combines academic course-work with articling requirements.<sup>4</sup>
>
> **articles**
>   an apprenticeship under 
>   a practising lawyer
>
> 4    William H Hurlburt, *The Self-Regulation of the Legal Profession in Canada and in England and Wales* 
>   (Calgary and Edmonton: Law Society of Alberta/ Alberta Law Reform Institute, 2000) at 69-78.

How did "[article](https://www.etymonline.com/word/article)" semantically specialize to this legal signification?

Comment: FYI, in U.S. practice, learning to practice law in this apprenticeship fashion was (and is) called "reading law." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reading_law

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no generalisation. The "articles" are *articles of clerkship*. The context permits the implication of that specific usage, in the same way that talking about "cars" at a racetrack isn't a generalisation of the word "car" - it's an implication of specifically *racecars*.

[Ancestry.co.uk](https://search.ancestry.co.uk/search/db.aspx?dbid=2380&geo_a=r&geo_s=uk&geo_t=uk&geo_v=2.0.0&o_iid=41012&o_lid=41012&o_sch=Web+Property) explains well what the articles actually are. Briefly, they are simply fixed-term apprenticeship contracts between an established practicing lawyer and a student who wishes to become a lawyer.

Comment: It is the *opposite* of a generalization, it is a *specialization*.

Comment: See also articles of incorporation/association/organisation, confederation, and impeachment.